# Get month from date parameter in MDX

Tags: ssrs-2008, mdx

I'm currently building reports using Reporting Services (and MDX language).
I get a date thanks to a parameter:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[retail sales amount] AS (
STRTOMEMBER(@TimecalendarTimecalendarmonthhierarchy)
, [Measures].[Retail sales amount invoiced including tax])
```

STRTOMEMBER(@TimecalendarTimecalendarmonthhierarchy) could be something like that [Time calendar].[Time calendar month hierarchy].[Time calendar date].&[2011-03-18T00:00:00]

I would like to only get the month of this parameter. When I use:

```
MTD([Time calendar].[Time calendar month hierarchy].[Time calendar date].&[2011-03-18T00:00:00]
, [Measures].[Retail sales amount invoiced including tax])
```

it works fine but that's not the case for

```
MTD(STRTOMEMBER(@TimecalendarTimecalendarmonthhierarchy)
, [Measures].[Retail sales amount invoiced including tax])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
MTD( STRTOMEMBER(@TimecalendarTimecalendarmonthhierarchy) ) * {[Measures].[Retail sales amount invoiced including tax]}
```

If it does not work, what is the result of :

```
STRTOMEMBER(@TimecalendarTimecalendarmonthhierarchy).name
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your solution doesn't work, and I don't know how to use the *.name in my query.

Comment: *.name, just change your measure and check the result. Doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 0):

**MTD** will give you the set of dates from the first date of the month to the date specified. If you want to get the month, you can either use **ANCESTOR** or **PARENT**. Parent will work if Month is directly above Date in your hierarchy. The difference between **SUM(MTD(date), measure)** and **(date.parent, measure)** is obvious when you think about previous months - if you go to a month which is in the past **MTD** will give you partial results as opposed to the month member itself (for dates other than the last date of the month).

**StrToMember** essentially translates a string to a member expression in MDX. There is no difference (functionally) between writing:

```
([Time].[Month].&[201001], [Measures].[SomeMeasure])
```

and

```
(StrToMember("[Time].[Month].&[201001]"), [Measures].[SomeMeasure])
```

It would be interesting to hear what exactly the error is when you execute your non-working expression in order to debug.

If you just want to get the month amount for the measure, you should write:

```
(StrToMember(@param).Parent, [Measures].[Retail sales amount...])
```

or (if you have more levels in between):

```
(Ancestor(StrToMember(@param), 
          [Time calendar].[<hierarchy>].[<month level>]), 
 [Measures].[Retail sales amount...])
```

Also, when using **MTD** you want to write:

```
SUM(MTD(<date member>), [Measure].[Some Measure])
```

instead of

```
MTD(<date member>, [Measure].[Some Measure])
```

have a look at [BOL's definition of MTD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144753.aspx)